# n-th Syzygies over a Cohen-Macaulay ring are Maximal Cohen-Macaulay for n big enough

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay

I am trying to proof the following:

> Let $R$ be a Cohen-Macaulay local ring with $\operatorname{dim}(R)=d$ and let 
>   $$
> 0\to M\to F_{n-1}\to F_{n-2}\to\cdots\to F_1\to F_0 
> $$
>   be an exact sequence of $R$-modules where each $F_i$ is finitely generated free. If $n\geq d$, then $M$ is a maximal Cohen-Macaulay module.

I am pretty sure that I have to use the fact, that the following conditions are equivalent for a noetherian, local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ and an $R$-module $M$:

(i) $M$ is a maximal Cohen-Macaualy module over $R$

(ii) $\operatorname{Ext}^{i}_R(R/\mathfrak{m},M)=0\quad  (i<d)$

(iii) $\operatorname{H}^{i}_{\mathfrak{m}}(M)=0\quad (i\not=d)$

where $\operatorname{H}^{i}_{\mathfrak{m}}(M)$ denotes the $i$-th cohomology functor with support on $\{\mathfrak{m}\}$.

I actually hope that it works with condition (ii) but I am not able to see the right useage of it yet, especially because the $F_i$ are free, so they don't kill $\operatorname{Ext}_R^{i}(R/\mathfrak{m},-)$ a priori. Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: $M$ is in fact an $n$th syzygy of a finite $R$-module, say $N$. Usually one denotes $M$ by $\Omega_n(N)$. We have: $\operatorname{depth}_R\Omega_n(N)\ge\min(\operatorname{depth}_RN+n,\operatorname{depth}R)$ and this solves your problem. (The inequality can be proved by using the Ext characterization of depth which satisfies your wish to use (ii).)

Comment: I think you should say that $M=0$ or MCM.

Comment: Yes I should say that. Acutually I wanted to assume that $M\not=0$.